Non transferable spl token mint without extensions
Is it possible to create non transferable spl token using old token standard? I guess that would be without usage of token extensions. (TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)

Yes, You could create a token with yourself as the freeze authority and freeze the token.
Paraphrasing the docs

If the mint contains a freeze_authority it can be used to issue FreezeAccount instructions that will render an Account unusable

async function freezeTokenAcc() {
    let mint = new PublicKey(""); // spl token mint

    let tokenAcc = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, signer.publicKey); //

    let txHash = await freezeAccount(conn, signer, tokenAcc, mint, signer);

    console.log(txHash);
}

You may then revoke the freeze authority to make sure that no one can thaw the accounts
